# Changing the color of a link after being clicked

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="default.asp" id="active" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

By default I set "Home" name color as active.

How do I dynamically change the color on the other links?

Answer (score 0):

add class names to those other links and use something like this

HTML

```
<a class="className">News</a>
<a class="className">Contact</a>
<a class="className">About</a>
```

CSS

```
.className{
   color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add a class to determine `active`.

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/ud6RV/1/

The idea here is that you want to modify a **specific link**. So why not give it a **class name**?. This will let you do all sorts of powerful things to one specific **element** on the page.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
a, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
    color:#00F;
}

li.active a {
    color:#0F0;
}
```

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/ud6RV/1/

Answer (score 0):

You mean [LIKE THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/qB3my/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Use jQuery siblings

Answer (score 0):

I hope your asking to change the color of a visited link.Add the below css to your css code.

```
ul a:visited{ 

   background-color:yellow;
}
```